# When was "Show zoom option in main menu" implemented on Chrome for Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android

When did Chrome on Android allow us to "Show zoom option in the main menu"? I just found this out yesterday and now I can zoom in and out on websites like Safari for iPhone.

When was this implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Show zoom option in main menu" first appeared on Chrome Beta v111.0.5563.15 on February 9, 2023, and on Chrome stable v111.0.5563.48 on March 3, 2023.**

The first appearance of the current menu title was on [January 25](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/930def07231e1192b6b4e280847ad3bcffbed498%5E%21/#F0), which was included in [Chrome Beta v111.0.5563.15](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2023/02/chrome-beta-for-android-update_9.html)

```
       <message name="IDS_PAGE_ZOOM_ALWAYS_SHOW_PREFERENCE_TITLE" desc="Title of the preference that allows the user to always show the menu item for zoom">
-        Show zoom
+        Show zoom option in main menu
       </message>
```

It was not until [27 February](https://blog.google/products/android/new-android-features-february-2023/) that the feature was officially introduced.

> #### Customize your Android
>
> You can now [easily increase the size of content on Chrome](https://www.android.com/google-features-on-android/february-2023/#google-chrome) — including text, images, video and interactive controls — by up to 300% to suit your vision preferences while still preserving the page layout. This includes the ability to set your preferred content size as a default so you don’t have to change it every time you open up Chrome. Try it today within [Chrome Beta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.beta) via Settings > Accessibility, before it [officially rolls](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome) out in March.

According to APK Mirror, the earliest version of Chrome stable after this Chrome Beta was [v111.0.5563.48](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/chrome/chrome-111-0-5563-48-release/).

Comment: Btw. What keywords did you type in Google? I couldn't find anything on page zoom on site:stackexchange.com or even a simple Google search

Comment: @BigJoe I googled "show zoom option in main menu chrome android" and found [an article by The Verge](https://www.theverge.com/2023/2/27/23615602/google-chrome-page-zoom-android-accessibility) which linked to [the official announcement](https://blog.google/products/android/new-android-features-february-2023/). Then I searched for the APK of Chrome Beta on [APK Mirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/chrome-beta/chrome-beta-111-0-5563-49-release/), which linked to the Chrome Releases blog, filtered by tags, which then linked to the Git log, and then searched for "zoom".